# Flurry logging events not always

Tags: android, session, tracking, flurry

I track my Application with flurry. At the flurry site i see a lot of events but i think flurry misses a lot of events messages. I use the android flurry sdk 3.2.2

So i used a proxy to watch the traffic of my phone.
The first time a start a session with onSessionStart i always see that flurry sends a post message to http://data.flurry.com/aap.do

While the session is active i track a couple of events with  FlurryAgent.logEvent(msg); and when the session ends flurry sends and the timeout (about 10 secs) is ready Flurry sends a message to data.flurry.com/aap.do with all the messages in it.

The problem is that this happens not always. in 50% of the cases Flurry sends nothing.
But when i start the session, by opening my app again, flurry sends the open session call to data.flurry.com/aap.do

I spend hours to find a pattern when the problem appears.

Would be great if anybody has a idea for me.

Marc

Comment: It would be great if you could clarify a little bit, are you certain that Flurry in fact does not log some of your events at all (meaning they will never appear in the Event Logs section, under Events, in your Flurry console)? Only if you can say this with certainty, it means that you have a problem. You need to keep in mind that Flurry has local storage of events, AFAIK in a database of its own, so it can persist the events and send them home later in case, for instance, the Internet connection is lost at some point while the events are being logged. These will then be sent at some later poin

Answer (score -2):

Flurry tries to send the events when they happen or during `onEndSession`. If it can't reach their server, perhaps due to lack of connectivity, it stores these events on a local database and try to send them again later, when you call `onStartSession`.

Also, ensures that you are calling `FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true)` and `FlurryAgent.setLogLevel(Log.DEBUG)`.